# Reshaping dataframe to wide, Variables to widen by timevar end up in some weird conglomerate?

Tags: r, reshape

I have successfully used reshape many times before, but I cannot get this to work.

My data Yield looks like:

```
FIPS  Year BaseVariance BaseMean Commodity.Code 
(chr) (int)   (num)       (num)      (num)
01001  1981     NA         20.8       41
01001  1982    6.125       19.05      41    
01001  1981     NA         27.4       11
01001  1982     123.245    35.25      11
```

I want to widen it to look like:

```
FIPS Year BaseVariance.11 Base Variance.41 .... BaseMean.11 Base Mean.41 ...
01001 1981    NA                 NA                 27.4        20.8
01001 1982    123.245          6.125                35.25       19.05
```

I was planning on dealing with missing values later, if that is possible? The code I was using was:

```
reshape(data=Yield, v.names=c('BaseVariance','BaseMean'),idvar=c('FIPS','Year'),timevar='Commodity.Code',direction='wide')
```

Using that, my result has these columns

```
FIPS Year BaseVariance.c(41,16,51,81,11,91)  BaseMean.c(41,16,51,81,11,91)
```

I dont understand where I went wrong.

Comment: Try it with `data=as.data.frame(Yield)` - as I suspect you have a *tibble* which won't play nicely with `reshape()`

Comment: This worked! Sorry it turned out to be so simple!

Answer (score 1):

Answering here to close it out, the problem was that the data I rbinded together was still a tibble.

A quick Yield<-as.data.frame(Yield) beforehand fixed it.

Thank you thelatemail